Ubuntu 24.04 SSH only works over Ethernet
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 desktop and have run into an issue with ssh.  Note, this machine is connected to the network via Ethernet.
I have configured ssh and have found the following behaviour:

I can ssh into the machine in question from another server that is connected via Ethernet to the network.  Indicating that ssh works.
I cannot ssh into the machine in question from any machine (phone, laptop etc) that is connected wirelessly to the network.  When I try to ssh, the connection simply times out.  There is no record of the connection attempt in the ssh logs.  However, I can successfully ping the machine indicating that it can be found.
I can connect to the server from point 1 that is also connected to the network via Ethernet from any machine (wired and wireless alike). Indicating that it is not a network issue.
This machine in question was previously running PopOS and ssh was working correctly with no issues indicating it is a problem with Ubuntu 24.04.

Any ideas anyone?

Bullet #2 suggests a firewall rule on the router to me.

I thought that as well except bullet 3 would indicate that it isn’t since I can connect to the server that is also connected via Ethernet.. unless somehow a random rule has been applied to this one machine

Use tcpdump, or wireshark if you prefer, to determine if the ssh packets even arrive at the computer and/or if it is responding at all. Example (change the NIC name to yours) sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -i enp1s0 port 22

Thanks for that @DougSmythies , I tried it and the packets are not arriving and the computer is not arriving at all…any ideas why?

It does sound like a firewall rule on the router, as per the earlier comment. You will have to edit your question with more information for us to be able to help more. What does "point 1" mean? Are you trying to SSH via IP address or computer name? If by computer name, have you tried by IP address?
